# Mid-budget 1990s movie with a vampire / Dracula

Tags: story-identification, movie

I’m trying to recall the title of a vampire movie which I believe came out in the 1990s or, less likely, early 2000s.

It involved a vampire (very possibly Dracula) who was chained up for much of the movie in some sort of warehouse or gym or something. I believe the movie involved a group of college students and may have had a professor character.

I recall that towards the end of the movie when the vampire got free of his restraints one of the students tried throwing a large number of something like beans or rice grains or something which the vampire was compelled to count, but which he was able to count very quickly.

I feel 65% sure this movie may have been a sequel.

Comment: There was also a similar scene in an *X Files* episode -- Mulder escaped some peril by knowing that vampires often had OCD and would compulsively count small objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is *[Dracula 2: Ascension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dracula_II:_Ascension)*.

> Filmed entirely in Romania by Castel Film Studios, the film is the sequel to Dracula 2000. It was released direct-to-video on June 7, 2003. The film marks one of the very few cinematic portrayals of certain aspects of vampire lore, such as a vampire's compulsive need to count mustard seeds and untie knots.

Comment: It is, thanks. I was just about to hit delete when you answered because I figured it out from a Wikipedia list. Man, you are quick on the draw! :) This comment will self destruct.

Comment: @Hack-R - The seed-counting was a giveaway. It's one of the less known aspects of Dracula that often gets missed out of vampire films.